# Concat method returns empty string while + operator works fine

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am writing a program to concatenate a string to make it repeat a number of times but on using `concat` method it always returns an empty string. I have solved the problem using `+` operator. But I still want to figure why `concat` is returning empty string.

Here is the code

```
let repeatStr = (str, num) => {
    let newStr = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
        newStr.concat(str); 
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Comment: You need to use the return value of concat()

Comment: BTW incase you didn't know, you can just use the [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function to repeat a string rather than creating a new function

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+%22concat%22+doesn%E2%80%99t+change+string) of [String Concat not working in scope JS](/q/48744357/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because `concat` method does not modify the string in-place, and you need to assign its result to some variable. If instead you replace that line in your code with `newStr = newStr.concat(str);` it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) returns a new string, and the original is **unmodified**. You can reassign to the same variable.

Note: You can also use the `+` operator.

```js
let repeatStr = (str, num) => {
    let newStr = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
        //newStr = newStr.concat(str); //Both work
        newStr += str;
    }
    return newStr;
}

console.log(repeatStr('x',3));
```

Comment: `concat` returns with string not `array`

Comment: @Joseph Yup, this applies for string. Changed the wording. Btw, `concat` is method on both the string and array prototype. And it returns the new value in both the cases.

Comment: Yeah, you are right but in this case, you are talking about `string` not `array`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the definition of [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) in **MDN**

> The `concat()` method concatenates the string arguments to the
> calling string and **returns a new string**.

that is means that it doesn't change the old value of your variable
so all you need is to re-assign your variable with the new value

```js
let repeatStr = (str, num) => {
    let newStr = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
       newStr = newStr.concat(str); 
    }
    return newStr;
}

console.log(repeatStr('welcome', 2))
```

there is another simple solution you could use [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function it used for this purpose like this

```js
console.log("welcome".repeat(3))
```